Selenium: How to fix PATH selector
I'm using a script to automate adding names from a website to a .csv using selenium, and for some reason the script no longer works when it has worked in months past. It's a bit of a long one, but it manages to log in, but cannot access the contact search page. Here is the part where it fails:
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from time import sleep
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
import re

# Username and Password
username = "XXXX"
password = "yyyyy"

### Web Driver Setting
### Download new version of ChromeDriver into same folder
driver_path = "C:/Users/owner/Downloads/chromedriver-win64/chromedriver-win64/chromedriver.exe"
chrome_service = ChromeService(executable_path=driver_path)
#options=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=chrome_service, options=options)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=chrome_service)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
# driver.get(('https://www.editorialmanager.com/ijrm/default1.aspx'))
driver.get(("https://www.editorialmanager.com/ijrm/default2.aspx"))

sleep(10)
driver.switch_to.default_content()
# FINDING an input:
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="content"]'))
driver.switch_to.frame(
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/iframe")
)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="username"]').send_keys(username)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@id="passwordTextbox"]').send_keys(password)

driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="emLoginButtonsDiv"]/input[3]').click()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
sleep(5)

# ### Going to the Search People Page
driver.switch_to.default_content()
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="content"]'))
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
wait.until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ctl00_Folders_SearchPeople"]'))
).click()
sleep(3)

The error I get is this:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\owner\Documents\Python\webscrape.py", line 52, in <module>
    wait.until(
  File "C:\Users\owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 95, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7A8D01502+60802]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7A8C7AC02]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7A8B37CE4]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7A8B86D4D]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7A8B86E1C]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7A8BCCE37]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7A8BAABBF]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7A8BCA224]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7A8BAA923]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7A8B78FEC]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7A8B79C21]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7A900411D+3217821]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7A90460B7+3488055]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7A903F03F+3459263]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7A8DBB846+823494]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7A8C85F9F]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7A8C80EC4]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7A8C81052]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7A8C718A4]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFF23DC257D+29]
    RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFF247EAA48+40]

I think the layout of the site has changed, and I can't seem to find the ID to enter the contact search, or substitute the new PATH. What should I do?

If we can't log in, I'm not sure how we're going to be able to help you. We still need info on which line the error is occurring. Post the relevant HTML as text, also properly formatted. Edit your question and add this info.

Looks like the id attribute of the element which you previously found at //*[@id="ctl00_Folders_SearchPeople"] is no longer there so you are getting a timeout when calling wait.until.
As mentioned by @JeffC, without any domain knowledge/context and access to the HTML source code it's hard to help beyond the above information.
If you can find the updated id then you should just need to replace it on the below line of code,
wait.until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="{new-id}"]'))
).click()

